# Can "axiomatically" be used in this way?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Quick question, is this sayable, can you use "axiomatically" like this:

Conventional wisdom has us thinking that technological, social and scientific **progress is axiomatically a good thing**, but is it really ?

---

For comparison, the initial sentence I wrote was:

Conventional wisdom has us thinking that technological, social and scientific **progress is necessarily only a good thing**, but is it really ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could say this, although the word "axiom", as in, a phrase that is self-evidently true, is not a particularly common one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly how the word should be used.